# Unity: Record video from device camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, video-capture

I want a plugin or a library or a way to record video (sure with sound) in unity (windows standalone) from device camera.

Currently, I am able to take screenshots using this camera. Someone says that I can take many screenshots and convert it to one video file.

I found a plugin on Asset store called [Camera Shoot](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/camera-shot-19682)

I want something like it but for windows.

**Edit 1:**

Now I am using a library that captures video from unity camera (virtual camera inside unity). I am previewing my camera feed on a canvas that is not shown in my application and I use this library to record this video.

This may solve my problem, but another problem was found that I need to record microphone voice to add this audio to the recorded video.

So now I am recording video (without sound) from the library, and record voice from microphone using another code, and after finish recording, I merge these 2 files together to get my desired file.

A new problem appears again. The merging process (muxing and compressing) takes a long time (more than 10% of the recorded time) which makes leads to many issues.

So I need another solution and prefered to be a plugin like the one above.

**Edit 2:**

I tried Unity VideoCapture Example in both editor and build. In unity editor, the application runs without errors but it didn't enter to this function "VideoCapture.CreateAsync()", as they said it didn't work with the editor.

When I tried to build to windows standalone build, it gives me this error : "Assets/Scripts/Controllers/Other/VideoCaptureExample.cs(4,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebCam' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.XR.WSA'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and working on this issue for about 2 months, I found [Capture Manager SDK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK).

It is for windows but the author has 2 demos for unity to record screenplay and not the camera feed. I asked him if it can capture video from the camera and he made a unity example that do what I want.

I have tested the unity demo and it works as expected.

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: ok. I found a working link to download it. When I selected he options as shown in this screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/FM1rU4Z), and clicked on the start button, I expected the webcam of my laptop to turn on, nothing happened.

Comment: The link is updated. @vipin8169 you can contact the owner of this library he has a good response. I was making a windows app for custom device and he helped me a lot to run the library on it.

Comment: I contacted him. My needs are a little different, so he said that I might need to modify his C++ code to fit my needs. I guess I will skip this :(

Comment: @vipin8169 if you didn't find another solution I advise you to ask him for modification