# How to record video with device camera in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first question post here. Please go easy on me.
I want to be able to record videos with device camera in Unity.
I can play the camera video as a video texture using WebCamTexture, but cannot save the video as a .mp4 file or something in the device. 
Is there any way to do it inside Unity?
Thank you very much.

Basically, I want to be able to record videos with device camera and save them in device as .mp4 files, just like a normal camera app, but with Unity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity: Record video from device camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403771/unity-record-video-from-device-camera)

Comment: @snipsnipsnip unfortunately the answer there is only a URL that is broken ...

Comment: Oops, sorry for crappy suggestion. Retracted :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin available in the unity asset store >>
[CameraShot plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/camera-shot-19682)